# How to get the equilibrium index of an array in O(n)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I have done a test in C++ asking for a function that returns one of the indices that splits the input vector in 2 parts having the same sum of the elements, for eg: for the `vec = {1, 2, 3, 5, 4, -1, 1, 1, 2, -1}`, it may return 3, because 1+2+3 = 6 = 4-1+1+1+2-1. So I have done the function that returns the correct answer:

```
int func(const std::vector< int >& vecIn)
{
   for (std::size_t p = 0; p < vecin.size(); p++)
   {
      if (std::accumulator(vecIn.begin(), vecIn.begin() + p, 0) == 
          std::accumulator(vecIn.begin() + p + 1, vecIn.end(), 0))
             return p;
   }
   return -1;
}
```

My problem was when the input was a very long vector containing just 1 (or -1), the return of the function was slow. So I have thought of starting the search for the wanted index from middle, and then go left and right. But the best approach I suppose is the one where the index is in the merge-sort algorithm order, that means: n/2, n/4, 3n/4, n/8, 3n/8, 5n/8, 7n/8... where n is the size of the vector. Is there a way to write this order in a formula, so I can apply it in my function?

Thanks

---

**EDIT**
After some comments I have to mention that I had done the test a few days ago, so I have forgot to put and mention the part of no solution: it should return -1... I have updated also the question title.

Comment: By doing cumulative sum, you may do the job in `O(n)`.

Comment: I am not really understanding the comment...

Comment: The comment would be clearer if it mentioned `std::partial_sum`. You're needlessly redoing the same calculations over and over. That said, it helps to realize that you're looking for `LeftHalf(i) = RightHalf(i)`  Since `Total = LeftHalf(i) + RightHalf(i)` for any `i`, it follows that `Total = 2 * LeftHalf(i)`. You don't need a cumulative sum at all.

Comment: I think you should consider rephrasing the question, because up to now, all answers tell you how to solve your actual problem, but they do not really refer to the question in the header or the question you ask in your last sentence. Seems like a typical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Comment: You should also consider, that the solution might be ambigious since negative values are allowed.

Comment: @Gombat: Doesn't even need negative numbers for that. `{1 0 1}` is already ambiguous. If you allow empty subsets, `{0}` already is ambiguous (i.e. there are no unique solutions if the input has length 1, because input {n} has no solutions when n!=0)

Comment: Here, I have edited the question, sorry for the ambiguities... Any other remarks for improving it? :)

Comment: Is it a strict requirement that both parts have the same sum or should the difference of the sums be minimized?

Comment: Both parts have the same sum

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Specifically for this problem, I would use the following algorithm:

1. Compute the total sum of the vector. This gives two sums (empty vector, and full vector)
2. for each element in order, move one element from full to empty, which means adding the value of next element from sum(full) to sum(empty). When the two sums are equal, you have found your index.

This give a o(n) algorithm instead of o(n2)

Answer (score 4):

You can solve the problem much faster without calling `std::accumulator` at each step:

```
int func(const std::vector< int >& vecIn)
{
   int s1 = 0;
   int s2 = std::accumulator(vecIn.begin(), vecIn.end(), 0);
   for (std::size_t p = 0; p < vecin.size(); p++)
   {
       if (s1 == s2)
           return p;
       s1 += vecIn[p];
       s2 -= vecIn[p];
   }
}
```

This is `O(n)`. At each step, `s1` will contain the sum of the first `p` elements, and `s2` the sum of the rest. You can update both of them with an addition and a subtraction when moving to the next element.

Since `std::accumulator` needs to iterate over the range you give it, your algorithm was `O(n^2)`, which is why it was so slow for many elements.

Comment: You don't even need to update `s2, if you divide it by 2 up front. (And for odd `s2` there is no integer solution anyway.)

Comment: @MSalters the sums are of numbers from the array, which can be anything. I don't follow how dividing by 2 would work here.

Comment: Simple: If there's a solution s1 == s2 and of course s1+s2 == total then s1 == total/2. Basic algebra, eliminating one variable from a pair of equations. To make the change smaller, I didn't propose to rename `s2` into `total`.

Comment: std::accumulate() is the function [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/accumulate/)

Answer (score 2):

Considering MSalters comments, I'm afraid another solution would be better. If you want to use less memory, maybe the selected answer is good enough, but to find the possibly multiple solutions you could use the following code:

```
static const int arr[] = {5,-10,10,-10,10,1,1,1,1,1};
std::vector<int> vec (arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) );

// compute cumulative sum
std::vector<int> cumulative_sum( vec.size() );
cumulative_sum[0] = vec[0];
for ( size_t i = 1; i < vec.size(); i++ )
{ cumulative_sum[i] = cumulative_sum[i-1] + vec[i]; }

const int complete_sum = cumulative_sum.back();

// find multiple solutions, if there are any
const int complete_sum_half = complete_sum / 2; // suggesting this is valid...
std::vector<int>::iterator it = cumulative_sum.begin();
std::vector<int> mid_indices;
do {
  it = std::find( it, cumulative_sum.end(), complete_sum_half );

  if ( it != cumulative_sum.end() )
  { mid_indices.push_back( it - cumulative_sum.begin() ); ++it; }

} while( it != cumulative_sum.end() );

for ( size_t i = 0; i < mid_indices.size(); i++ )
{ std::cout << mid_indices[i] << std::endl; }

std::cout << "Split behind these indices to obtain two equal halfs." << std::endl;
```

This way, you get all the possible solutions. If there is no solution to split the vector in two equal halfs, mid_indices will be left empty. 
Again, you have to sum up each value only once.

<s>My proposal is this:</s>

```
static const int arr[] = {1,2,3,5,4,-1,1,1,2,-1};
std::vector<int> vec (arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) );

int idx1(0), idx2(vec.size()-1);
int sum1(0), sum2(0);
int idxMid = -1;
do {
  // fast access without using the index each time.
  const int& val1 = vec[idx1];
  const int& val2 = vec[idx2];

  // Precompute the next (possible) sum values. 
  const int nSum1 = sum1 + val1;
  const int nSum2 = sum2 + val2;

  // move the index considering the balanace between the 
  // left and right sum.
  if ( sum1 - nSum2 < sum2 - nSum1 )
  { sum1 = nSum1; idx1++; }
  else
  { sum2 = nSum2; idx2--; }

  if ( idx1 >= idx2 ){ idxMid = idx2; }

} while( idxMid < 0 && idx2 >= 0 && idx1 < vec.size() );

std::cout << idxMid << std::endl;
```

It does add every value only once no matter how many values. Such that it's complexity is only O(n) and not O(n^2).

The code simply runs from left and right simultanuously and moves the indices further if it's side is lower than the other.

Comment: I don't think this works for all inputs. The idea behind `if (sum1 <= sum2) sum1 += vec[idx++]` clearly is to add a value to `sum1` if it's the smaller of the two. However, `vec[idx++]` can be negative. Consider the situation where sum1 is 5, sum2 is 6, and the last remaining element between the left and right half is -1. Clearly this must be added to s2, so you get 5 & 5. Your algorithm adds -1 to 5, giving an incorrect 4==6 result.

Comment: for  { 10, 1, -2, 4, 7 }; the algorith fails to find the right solution

Comment: Your `O(n)` vs `2*O(n)` is misleading as it is the "same" complexity, and even if you consider the factor, you doesn't count your additional `if` in your loop (so it may be seen as `5*O(n)`).

Comment: @ MSalters: You are right. I edited the code to consider negative values.

@ Jarod42: I deleted the 2*O(n) statement in the answer

@ Alexander: I edited the code, now it should work for all input without summing up at the beginning.

Comment: Still wrong. This algorithm can't backtrack. If it has 3 elements left that all should go to one side, but it chooses the wrong side, then the algorithm doesn't find the correct solution. And the algorithm can't know the right side to pick (idx1 or idx2) with 3 numbers left because it doesn't consider the middle value, which may have any value (positive or negative). That is to say, with numbers `a b c` left, for any `sum1`and `sum2` there is a value `b=(sum2-sum1)-a-c` so that all 3 should be added to sum1, and for `b=(sum1-sum2)-a-c` all 3 should be added to sum2.  You need `b` to choose.

Comment: Thinking about your answer and considering that the middle value can be anything, maybe it would be better to choose another solution.

Comment: what about { 10, -1, 2, -2, 4, 7 };

Comment: With the updated solution, it says you should split behind index 0.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the actual question: Your sequence n/2, n/4, 3n/5, n/8, 3n/8 can be rewritten as

```
1*n/2
1*n/4 3*n/4
1*n/8 3*n/8 5*n/8 7*n/8
...
```

that is to say, the denominator runs from i=2 up in powers of 2, and the nominator runs from j=1 to i-1 in steps of 2. However, this is not what you need for your actual problem, because the example you give has n=10. Clearly you don't want n/4 there - your indices have to be integer.

The best solution here is to recurse. Given a range [b,e], pick a value middle (b+e/2) and set the new ranges to [b, (b+e/2)-1] and [(b+e/2)=1, e]. Of course, specialize ranges with length 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1):

You want n<sup>th</sup> term of the series you mentioned. Then it would be:

```
numerator:   (n - 2^((int)(log2 n)) ) *2 + 1
denominator:  2^((int)(log2 n) + 1)
```

Comment: How does this relate to the question at all?

Comment: @IVlad, He mentioned that he wanted to access elements in specific order, given by n/2, n/4, 3n/4, n/8, 3n/8, 5n/8, 7n/8... where `n` is the number of elements in array. So, I gave him formula to generate series, 1/2, 1/4, 3/4, 1/8, 3/8 ... and so on. see last line of the question, though I didn't understand the question fully because of his poor wording.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same question in Codility tests. There is a similar looking answer above (didn't pass some of the unit tests), but below code segment was successful in tests.

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Returns -1 if equilibrium point is not found
// use long long to support bigger ranges
int FindEquilibriumPoint(vector<long> &values) {
    long long lower = 0;
    long long upper = std::accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), 0);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {

        upper -= values[i];

        if (lower == upper) {
            return i;
        }

        lower += values[i];
    }

    return -1;
}


int main() {
        vector<long> v = {-1, 3, -4, 5, 1, -6, 2, 1};

        cout << "Equilibrium Point:" << FindEquilibriumPoint(v) << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

> Output 
>   Equilibrium Point:1

Answer (score 0):

Here it is the algorithm in Javascript:

```
function equi(arr){

var N = arr.length;
if (N == 0){ return -1};

var suma = 0;
for (var i=0; i<N; i++){
    suma += arr[i];
}

var suma_iz = 0;
for(i=0; i<N; i++){
    var suma_de = suma - suma_iz - arr[i];
    if (suma_iz == suma_de){
        return i};
    suma_iz += arr[i];
}

return -1;
```

}

As you see this code satisfy the condition of O(n)